# How to change an OS of dual boot?

Tags: linux, multi-boot, grub

I have Kali Linux and Windows 10 installed on my system, with GRUB bootloader. The Windows OS is installed on my HDD while the Linux is installed on my SSD(partitioned in half). Now I want to replace my Kali Linux with Ubuntu without losing my Windows 10, previously I've tried doing it on a different PC but ended up with the new GRUB(of Ubuntu) not detecting the Windows, is it possible to change the Kali Linux to Ubuntu without resetting the GRUB?

Answer (score 0):

First you have to delete the partition in which you installed kali linux (do this in windows). Then you have to [delete the kali linux grub bootloader](https://askubuntu.com/questions/429610/uninstall-grub-and-use-windows-bootloader)(read the first answer and replace ubuntu in last step with kali). Sometimes you may not be able to find the grub in this way; then list the partitions and see if there is an EFI system belonging to kali and delete the partition(be careful as you cannot directly delete an EFI partition;so read [this](https://www.easeus.com/partition-master/delete-efi-system-partition.html)). If you cannot do this you can change the boot priority in your BIOS menu to windows first so that you boot into windows by default.
Now you can proceed to install ubuntu. If you do not see windows bootloader in the grub menu of ubuntu then boot into ubuntu, then [update the grub](https://askubuntu.com/questions/281119/how-do-you-run-update-grub). You can also install grub-customizer and perform the update the GUI way.
There is obviously no way of replacing Kali linux with ubuntu in a click so good luck.

Comment: Why all this hassle though? Won't it be enough to boot into the Ubuntu installer and tell it to use the existing Kali partition?

Comment: @tripleee he asked that he wanted to replace the kali partition with ubuntu

Comment: It's just a partition; the installer would be replacing its contents completely and updating the bootloader anyway, won't it?

Comment: You can do that but it is the same thing and anyway you have to remove the grub of kali linux and it is not very hard to delete the partition in windows too. Nice idea though